# Saving Working Directory path when distributing a project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio you can specify the working directory of your executable by going to `propject properties > debugging` (this is needed to run Ogre projects for example from within Visual Studio). My working directory is usually in the form of `$(SolutionDir)\bin\release\$(ProjectName).exe`.

When I distribute the project, the working directory text box is wiped (I am assuming it is saved in the .suo files) as I distribute only the `.proj` and `.sln` files. Is there any way to preserve/save that so that when I distribute the project, the users don't have to put the working directory every time?

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no way to 'preserve' the info. Visual Studio 2010 moves the options so that they are not user independent anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The debugging settings are per project file and are stored in the project .user file.

Comment: Ah so it is the .user file. Any chance the working directory can be automatically filled in?